# AWS EC2 - Can't launch an instance - Account blocked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch an EC2 instance on my personal AWS account, but getting the following error:

```
Launch Failed
This account is currently blocked and not recognized as a valid account. Please contact aws-verification@amazon.com if you have questions.
Hide launch log
Creating security groups

Successful (sg-77e2ae10)
Authorizing inbound rules

Successful
Initiating launches

FailureRetry
```

So I sent an email explaining, and got the following answer:

```
Greetings from Amazon Web Services.

Thank you for contacting us regarding this matter. We reviewed your account and confirmed that your Amazon Web Services account has been successfully verified. You may now begin launching instances.

Thank you for using Amazon Web Services.


Sincerely,
Amazon Web Services
```

But tried again and got the same error. Sent a new email, and got the same answer. Retried and still can't launch...

Apparently there's no problem with my payment method or anything like that. Also tried to launch it in different regions, like n. virginia, oregon and são paulo. Got the same error.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How are you launching, via the console or some other automated way (cli, cloud formation etc)?

Comment: @E.J.Brennan I'm using the browser (aws console)

Comment: It does not seem uncommon for account state changes to take a few hours to impact all services.  Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Can you use other services? I think it is not effected to your account, just wait around 1 day to effect and retry later.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here is an email that I got from AWS:

> Dear AWS Customer,
>
> Thank you for signing up with Amazon Web Services!
>
> As a new customer, you can launch Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instances in 3 AWS regions. We suggest you to use the regions US East (N. Virginia), US East (Ohio), US West (Oregon), but if you prefer other regions please contact us at <s>aws-verification@amazon.com</s> and let us know which 3 regions are more convenient for you. You can find the list of regions and which services are available in each of the regions at http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/globalinfrastructure/regional-product-services/. Please make sure you are not running EC2 instances in the region you are transitioning from.
>
> If you have a use case that requires you to run EC2 instances in more than 3 regions, please contact us at <s>aws-verification@amazon.com</s> describing your use case and we will increase the number of available regions.
>
> This limitation is temporary and only affects EC2 – other AWS services are available in all regions.
>
> Sincerely,
> Amazon Web Services

So please change your region to **US West (Oregon)** or **US East (N. Virginia)** or **US East (Ohio)** and then it will works.
If you still want to use other regions, you may submit a request on this page:
https://support.aws.amazon.com/#/contacts/aws-account-verification

Comment: I wonder why this was not the accepted answer. this totally works (moving region to the specified regions) unless @ronan-lopes has a preference on the region.

Comment: It sure would be nice if the error message said that instead of requiring us to email support and wait, get tired of waiting, then googling for another solution.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me tried all three regions. What other else will be the possibility of the error

Comment: @Shamoon97 I also tried with 3 region, but no use. same error is showing. Have u got any solution?

Comment: same with me too. I tried all regions, do we have a solution for this please?

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan Sorry, it has been a long time since the solution worked for me. AWS may update the rules.

Comment: Same thing here it is not working. I've change to all four locations but no result the same error appears every time.

Comment: Same, getting same error for all three regions

Answer (score 9):

I recently hit this issue as well while trying to create an instance from the US East region. It seems that the "root cause" was that I was attempting to launch an instance while logged in as the root user.

One is able to create an admin user that can log in to the AWS console. As the root user, navigate to IAM Dashboard > Users > "Add User"

There's a box to check to allow console access the new user. When launching an EC2 instance, again from `us-east-1` the launch sequence succeeded.

Comment: People arriving at this google search in 2023 - this above is the answer.

Comment: As a person arriving in 2023. I followed the steps lined up above and still received the same error. However, after waiting around 5 minutes and running again it went through successfully.

Comment: Not work for me.

Comment: This worked for me. And to be clear you only need to check the box and wait. You dont need to make any changes to configuration.